# how to combine two columns in mysql and make it as one column?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
+-----+---------------+---------------+
| id  |    team_A     |    team_B     |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|  1  |   Barcelona   |  Real Madrid  |
+-----+---------------+---------------+
|  2  |     Milan     |     Inter     |
+-----+---------------+---------------+

select * from table and combine as team_c
```

and result should be like one column..

```
team_c as

barcelona
milam
real
inter
```

all rows should in **team_c** should be different..
because i need two show in an autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: What should be your final result in fact .. ??

Comment: two different columns should be as same columns with new rows..

Comment: @saivamshigupta follow my answer, i hope solve your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query :

```
select a.team_a as team_c from table a Union select b.team_b from table b
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you store that data into extra table. You can do using select query like

```
select team_a as team_c from table Union select team_b from table
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT team_A, team_B , CONCAT_WS('', team_A, team_B) AS team_C, from table;
```

You can combine them using `CONCAT_WS`.
Hope it will usefull!

Comment: the two columns are just combining (eg user,email = user email) but my requirment is user and in next row email

Comment: This is not what the user asked for

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168135/union-of-two-columns-in-the-same-table) should solve your question:

```
SELECT team_A AS team_C FROM table UNION SELECT team_B FROM table
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT CONCAT( team_A," ",team_B) AS team_c FROM table;
```

You can try this **output** will like

---

### Barcelona Real Madrid

### Milan Inter

Comment: This is not what the user asked for